# Lightbox not showing image caption

Tags: customization, theme-development, images, gallery, lightbox

I am using Jevelin theme and their Lightbox should showing image caption from alt attribute. Hovewer it doesn't works.

Here is the link: https://www.coleopterafarm.cz/galerie-zlatohlavci/

I am wondering around forums and tips but still without a success.

Could anyone help me with this please? Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi @Jaccob I've visited your site and clicked on images -> popup appeared and image loaded. It just needs some tome for image to be loaded.

Comment: I have checked website and I have found one think, below js file is not found in js folder https://www.coleopterafarm.cz/wp-content/themes/jevelin-child/js/scripts.js?ver=5.3.2    so please check it. it may help you to fix this issue.

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, photos are loading. There is no problem. JS was fixed Tanmay but it's just a child file without content. 

I am wondering how to get title or caption of images to show in that lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

Now I finded this in plugins.js

title:null

I tried to change that to title:'_wp_attachment_image_alt' but it just showed text "_wp_attachment_image_alt"

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP generates this html for gallery grid item:

```
<div class="sh-image-gallery-item">
  <div class="sh-gallery-item">
    <div class="post-meta-thumb">

      <img src="https://www.coleopterafarm.cz/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/PICT9418-660x660.jpg" alt="Carabus (Coptolabrus) smaragdinus brannicki">

      <a class="sh-overlay-style2" href="https://www.coleopterafarm.cz/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/PICT9418-1024x768.jpg" data-rel="lightcase:imgCollectionsh-image-gallery-simple-Bi7XU3vsdZ">
        <div class="sh-overlay-item">
           <div class="sh-overlay-item-open"></div>
        </div>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is JS script a part of bundled js file https://www.coleopterafarm.cz/wp-content/themes/jevelin/js/plugins.js expects `title="your title for image"` attribute for `<a class="sh-overlay-style2">`

So proper HTML would be

```
<div class="sh-image-gallery-item">
  <div class="sh-gallery-item">
    <div class="post-meta-thumb">

      <img src="https://www.coleopterafarm.cz/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/PICT9418-660x660.jpg" alt="Carabus (Coptolabrus) smaragdinus brannicki">

      <a class="sh-overlay-style2" title="Carabus (Coptolabrus) smaragdinus brannicki" href="https://www.coleopterafarm.cz/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/PICT9418-1024x768.jpg" data-rel="lightcase:imgCollectionsh-image-gallery-simple-Bi7XU3vsdZ">
        <div class="sh-overlay-item">
           <div class="sh-overlay-item-open"></div>
        </div>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way JS will use title from clicked item and display it as it should.
Also it's more a question to support of Jevelin theme devs https://themeforest.net/item/jevelin-multipurpose-premium-responsive-wordpress-theme/14728833/support
Probably they've fixed it in next theme's update.
Or you'll have to alter PHP yourself.